# Divide matrix lines into groups and get the group using the position

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, matrix

I have a matrix of tiles **120 lines * 75 columns** (960px * 600px). Each tile has 8px * 8px.

I divided the matrix lines into **30 groups**, which translates to **4 lines per group**.

When I mouseover each tile I need to **know the group of the tile**. The information I have is the y and x in px relative to the top left corner of the matrix. I also have the number of the tile (numbered like in the picture - not the same dimensions given before).

[image: matrix]

I'm coding this in **Javascript**. I have the following formula:

```
Math.trunc(y/(TILE_WIDTH*4));
```

It identifies well the first groups but as the y starts increasing it starts misidentifying the group. I have also tried round, floor and ceil with no success.

Comment: `Each tile has 8px * 8px.` does it have a border?

Comment: No borders, the photos are next to each other.

Comment: Could you log & add a table of `y` with each result?

Comment: @JonasWilms Here it is: https://gist.github.com/diogoredin/73aa7d183b6a65df26024dd7ba0f5f88. The format is [y,group]. The group function there is (y/(TILE_WIDTH*4)).
I did the logging by moving around the mouse so there are a few jumps and repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing number of tile (as I can see - numbered from 1), you can find group as

```
Math.trunc((number_of_the_tile - 1) / (columncount*4))
```